# Ruby incorrectly parses 2 digit year

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Ruby correctly parses the first date but the second one is incorrect. Tested with ruby 1.9.3 and 2.1.2.

Any idea how to get it to work consistently? (We are getting in birth dates as 2 digit years)

```
Date.strptime("10/11/89","%d/%m/%y")
=> Fri, 10 Nov 1989

Date.strptime("15/10/63","%d/%m/%y")
=> Mon, 15 Oct 2063
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `strptime` method is parsing the text "63" to the year 2063, not 1963 as you want.

This is because the method decides the century by using the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html).

The `chronic` gem has a similar issue because it decides the century, though differently.

A solution is to adjust the date:

```
d = Date.strptime("15/10/63","%d/%m/%y")
if d > Date.today
  d = Date.new(d.year - 100, d.month, d.mday)
end
```

In the comments of this post, Stefan suggests a good one liner:

```
d = d.prev_year(100) if d > Date.today
```

If you need speed, you can try optimizing like this:

```
d <= Date.today || d = d << 1200
```

Comment: or `d = d.prev_year(100) if d > Date.today`

Comment: Your second example doesn't take future dates within the current year into account.

Comment: @Stefan good points, thanks. I'll remove the second example -- it's not as simple and not as fast.

Comment: @stefan why would a date of birth be in the future?

Answer (score 5):

When using `%y` in `strptime`, the code assumes that values under 68 are considered in the 21st century, as descirbed [here](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-Format-Strptime-1.56/lib/DateTime/Format/Strptime.pm):

> The year within century (0-99). When a century is not otherwise specified (with a value for %C), values in the range 69-99 refer to years in the twentieth century (1969-1999); values in the range 00-68 refer to years in the twenty-first century (2000-2068).

In the `chronic` gem, incidentally, the cut-off year is 64:

```
Chronic.parse('15/10/64')
# => 1964-10-15 12:00:00 +0200

Chronic.parse('15/10/63')
# => 2063-10-15 12:00:00 +0300
```

Comment: Interesting that Chronic uses a different mapping. Ruby conforms to the POSIX standard.

Comment: @Stefan - They changed it just enough so they can confuse bsy :-P

Comment: Chronic uses a 50 year offset by default and 2014 - 50 = 1964

Comment: @UriAgassi thanks for digging into that! and yes, didn't know Chronic's limitations, however it did work for your specific example, just didn't do extensive testing! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Chronic gem has added an extended support parsing 2 digit years with `ambiguous_year_future_bias` option:

```
irb(main):029:0> Chronic.parse('15/10/99', ambiguous_year_future_bias: 10)
=> 2099-10-15 12:00:00 +0300
irb(main):030:0> Chronic.parse('15/10/99', ambiguous_year_future_bias: 50)
=> 1999-10-15 12:00:00 +0300
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the Chronic gem to your Gemfile

`gem 'chronic'`

Then just parse it:

```
Chronic.parse("15/10/68")
=> 1968-10-15 12:00:00 -0700
```

Comment: This only shifts the problem: `Chronic.parse("15/10/63")` returns 2063